# How many records i can insert using DynamoDb BatchWrite by Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

By using Boto3's batch insert, maximum how many records we can insert into Dynamodb's table. Suppose i'm reading my input json from S3 bucket which is of 6gb in size.

And it cause any performance issues while inserting as a batch. Any sample is helpful. I just started looking into this, based on my findings i'll update here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find information like this in the service documentation for [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html):

> A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests. Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB.

There are no performance issues, aside from consuming the write capacity units.

Comment: For single item its working fine. How can I write for 25 items in boto3. Help me if any sample ?

Comment: Also, how to make sure to handle failed items from each BatchWriteItem result by re-adding them back to the requests.

Comment: Here is a example of batchwriting:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#batch-writing

Comment: In link you've provided there is example with 50 entries being put into table. 
Here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-dynamodb-batching-dynamo_batching.py.html 
in samples on official docs, we can see 500 items being put into table. 
I don't know what to think

Answer (score 21):

You can use the Boto3 `batch_writer()` function to do this. The batch writer handles chunking up the items into batches, retrying, etc. You create the batch writer as a context manager, add all of your items within the context, and the batch writer sends your batch requests when it exits the context.

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('table-name')

with table.batch_writer() as writer:
    for item in table_data:
        writer.put_item(Item=item)
```

There's a complete working code example on GitHub here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/python/example_code/dynamodb/batching/dynamo_batching.py.

Comment: Is there a way to control the consumed write capacity using the Boto3 batch_writer?

Comment: this read all the data into memory before writing :(